# Relation between Adjacency Matrix and Incidence Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let the Adjacency matrix be A, and Incidence Matrix be B; 
'd' represents degree of given vertex

How do we prove $B.B^T=A+\begin{bmatrix}d(V_1) & 0 &\dots \\ 0 & d(V_2) & 0 & \dots\\ 0 &0 & d(V_3)&0&\dots \\ \vdots & & & \ddots \\ 0 &\dots & & & d(V_n) \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: $$\text{undirected graph with unoriented incidence matrix B}$$
$$\text{undirected unweighted noselfloop no-multiedge graph}$$
$$G: e1(v1-v2), e2(v1-v3), e3(v1-v4), e4(v3-v4)$$
$$A=\begin{matrix}0&1&1&1\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 1&0&0&1\\ 1&0&1&0\end{matrix}$$
$$D=\begin{matrix}3&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&2&0\\ 0&0&0&2\end{matrix}$$
$$\text{unoriented incidence matrix $B$,} b_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if link $i - j$ incident} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$$B=\begin{matrix}~&e1&e2&e3&e4\\ v1&1&1&1&0\\ v2&1&0&0&0\\ v3&0&1&0&1\\ v4&0&0&1&1\end{matrix}$$
$$\text{apparently }BB^T=A+D$$

Comment: see [Incidence_matrix in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix)

Answer (score 1):

1. What does each column $b_j$ of B encode, geometrically?
2. Can you show that $b_i\cdot b_j$ computes the number of edges that vertex $i$ and $j$ share?
3. The theorem should now be straightforward: consider the three cases where two vertices $i,j$ are adjacent, not adjacent, and equal.

Comment: 1. $b_j$ is encoding edges while $b_i$ encode vertices.
I dont understand what you meant in second and third descriptions

Comment: ah sorry, I meant columns rather than rows. I'll edit